# onSubmit not working on enter in render props (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, onsubmit

I need a button inside a form which triggers the `onSubmit` event when user presses the Enter button.

This is the example of a working solution:

```
<form onSubmit={() => console.log('ok')}>
  <button type="submit" autoFocus>Submit</button>
</form>
```

When the user presses Enter, `onSubmit` is properly triggered.

My problem is when I have to render this button in render props of a component:

```
<Component render={()=> (
  <button type="submit" autoFocus /> // here the button will not be focused
)}/>
```

So when I press Enter, nothing happens.

Is there any way to get a working solution using only html attributes?

Comment: Please explain what does that Component? pay attention to which native HTML button element can not take props as an attribute

Comment: Sure thing, I edited it as `props` there would not make any sense. The component comes from another library then I do not necessarily know what it does. For my specific use, the `Component` is `GoogleLogin` component from `react-google-login` library.

Comment: Please share codes of Component to better understanding and helping you

Comment: @L.PierRoberto Actually, you can solve it. See my updated answer. You have to render the button only if it is enabled, then the autofocus will apply. But still, this is very fragile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not working because in your example the button `onClick` event is not connected to the `GoogleLogin` or the wrapping `Component`.

Step by step:

Because of the `autoFocus`, when your button is rendered it is automatically focused. As soon as you click `enter` while it is still focused the click event of that button is fired.

In the pure `html` example the `onSubmit` of the form is triggered because the button has a `type="submit"`.

```
<form onSubmit={() => console.log('ok')}>
  <button type="submit" autoFocus>Submit</button>
</form>
```

So if you want your example to trigger the `GoogleLogin` on click of `enter`, you have to trigger it manually trough props on click of your button like that:

```
  <GoogleLogin
render={(renderProps) => (!renderProps.disabled ?
  <button  autoFocus onClick={renderProps.onClick}>
    This is my custom Google button
  </button>: null
)}
  />
```

Keep in mind, if the user clicks Tab, the autofocus will be lost and the `enter` input will not trigger the `onClick` event anymore.

Instead, you could set up an event listener which will listen for the `enter` input and trigger GoogleLogin as long as it is rendered, independently of the autoFocus. Or you let your user click that button instead of enter.

Comment: My current solution uses a `useEffect` which set up an event listener as you suggested, but I would like to avoid this in favour of html attributes. The solution you proposed is interesting but it doesn't work as `onClick` is not triggered with the `enter` input from the user.

Comment: for me it is working, here is a quick codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-google-login-forked-47brn?file=/src/index.js
Or the browser output here:
https://47brn.csb.app/
On render you can see that the button is focused and you can press Enter to trigger it.

Comment: Maybe you are losing the focus somewhere in between? E.g. clicking somewhere else will remove the button focus and it will break the on enter klick. That makes the solution very fragile.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. After trying a bit I found out that if you try to add to `GoogleLogin` the prop `disabled={renderProps.disabled}` it will remove the `autofocus`. I think that at the beginning the button is disabled and as soon as it gets enabled, the autofocus is lost.

Comment: Well yes disabled prop, removes the autoFocus. But that detail was not in your question.
In that case, I think it is not possible to solve this with autofocus and you will have to use an event listener.

Comment: Sure, my fault. I should have provided more information instead of writing `Component`. I thought that the problem was somehow in the use of the render props. Thanks for the great help.

Comment: @L.PierRoberto Actually, you can solve it. See my updated answer.
You have to render the button only if it is enabled, then the autofocus will apply.
But still, this is very fragile.